# What are the benefits of turning in research and where can I see them?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've been turning in various fragments for research in Haven to Minaeve, but I'm not entirely sure what benefits I gain from this. It is supposed to help me exploit weaknesses in enemies, but I could not find any details.

What exactly are the benefits of turning in research items? Is there an ingame way to see all the benefits you already unlocked?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look in your codex entries for creatures.  As you flip through the cards, you'll see black and white pips in the upper right.  One pip means you have descriptive text.  Two pips means you have an advantage.  Scroll to the bottom of the descriptive text to see the advantage you unlocked.

If you've turned in some material for a given creature codex entry, you will also notice a progress bar displayed on the card.